# Teradata dbc.columns: Why does ColumnFormat column differ from the table DDL's column definition?

Tags: teradata

I run this SQL:

```
select * from dbc.columns
where
    databasename = 'mydb' and
    tablename = 'mytable' and
    columntype = 'ts' and
    1=1
order by tablename;
```

The column is a Timestamp(6) and its ColumnFormat column returns `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.s(6)`.  However, when I view the DDL with `show table mydb.mytable`, the column format for the column shows as `yyyy-mm-ddbhh:mi:ss.s(6)`.  Notice the minute format strings.  The dbc view shows `mm` while the table DDL shows `mi`.  What's up with that?

Comment: What is returned for the timestamp columns on DBC.DBQLogTbl?

Comment: I'm not really sure how I'd use the data from that view.  What I am doing is using the data from dbc.columns to write a .NET utility that generates table DDL.  When I attempt to use the string value from the ColumnFormat column to create the DDL, I get an error when I attempt to execute the DDL because it doesn't recognize `mm` as a valid format string for minutes (that's `mi`).

Comment: What I was trying to get at was that when I run your query and reference the column information for DBQLogTbl in DBC the ColumnFormat matched what SHOW TABLE produced. Something seems awry that ColumnFormat would be different than what SHOW TABLE produces. What happens if you create a copy of the table in question using CREATE TABLE AS ... WITH NO DATA;?

Comment: Good call on creating a copy.  When I did, the ColumnFormat for the copy shows the proper formart string.  The original table was created way back in 2003, so I am guessing older Teradata versions used that old format.  If that's the case, it's obvious that upgrading the database to a newer version doesn't update metadata like it should.

Comment: Open an incident with the GSC